# How do I create and validate a form for a belongs_to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The form contains a lookup key (user input) that will be used to create the belongs_to model (a token table). That is, the lookup key is a property of the parent record. In my case it is an email and I'd like to validate its format *before* proceeding with the creation of the belongs_to object.

```
class UserToken < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates_presence_of :user

 attr_accessor :email # required to validate form input?
 validates :email, presence: true, format: /.+@.+/
end
```

The issue is that I have to call valid? before assigning the user property of the UserToken model. The user property is obviously nil since I need to validate the email input and look up the record first.

I don't think removing the belongs_to validation is a correct path. What should I be doing?

Comment: Can you set the user association at the same time you validate the email (use a custom validation)?

Comment: No, the actual input has not been validated yet.